# excel vba - protetcted sheet delete row

Tags: excel, vba

I learned that I need to write a macro if I want users to delete rows on a protected sheet.

This is the code I got by googling around:

```
Sub delete_row()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="justme"
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="justme"
End Sub
```

Where exactly should I place this code? Will it work if multiple rows are deleted etc.?

MrExcel is down today, so limited options.

Comment: It depends on how you want to extend the functionality to the user. Would you like the user to select the rows which needs to be deleted?

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes, like they usually do it on excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this in a module

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteMe()
    Dim Ret As Range, Cl As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Ret = Application.InputBox("Please select the Cells", "Delete Rows", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="justme"

    If Not Ret Is Nothing Then Ret.EntireRow.Delete

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="justme"
End Sub
```

When you run the above macro it will ask you to select the cell(s). Whatever cells you select, the entire row will get deleted.

Comment: there is no way to hijack excel's delete? Meaning they select the rows, and press delete (or right-click and select delete), and that gets captured by vba?

Comment: There is an alternative :) Assign a shortcut key to the above macro. So all the user needs to do is press the shortcut key and the above code will run :)

Comment: you're so awesome. That's what I was thinking: there has to be another way. Can you point me towards assigning macro to a shortcut-key? http://kb.iu.edu/data/ahbm.html is this good enough?